# To show that $e^x > 1+x$ for any $x\ne 0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, derivatives, proof-verification, exponential-function

$$e^x>1+x$$

is  what I want to show.

So let's define a function:

$$h\left(x\right)=e^x-x-1$$

and investigate its derivative:

$$h'\left(x\right)=e^x-1$$.

Easy to see that at $x=0$ it has a critical point and it is a minimum, and therefore for any other value that isn't $0$ we'll get a value that is bigger then the minimum $f(0)=0$, in other words, for each $x\ne 0$, $h\left(x\right)>0$, meaning $e^x-x-1>0$ meaning that:

$$e^x>x+1$$

Comment: your proof is correct.

Comment: What is the question? Your analysis is correct.

Comment: I performed some minor edits on the spelling and grammar of your post.  Nice question, ***endorsed!***

Comment: I edited again to try and clarify the *question*; still needs a little more work but we've hit the 9 edits point and if any more is done the system will notify moderators, and I don't feel like bugging them with this . . . what to do?   Thinking . . . anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: @RobertLewis I don't understand why you're editing that question so much... Besides in general questions contain a question mark.

Comment: @Najib Isrissi:  before I respond in greater detail, let me ask if you have looked at the edit history of this question? (Note the question mark, if you will!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think our OP's proof has the right idea, especially when taken in light of the comments.   Here's a way to work it which avoids explicit use of minima/maxima, and hence avoids any pitfalls inherent in such methods:

One can also look at the function

$\alpha(x) = e^{-x}(1 + x); \tag{1}$

we have

$\alpha(0) = 1 \tag{2}$

and

$\alpha'(x) = -e^{-x}(1 + x) + e^{-x}  = -xe^{-x}; \tag{3}$

we see that

$x > 0 \Rightarrow \alpha'(x) < 0 \tag{4}$

and

$x < 0 \Rightarrow \alpha'(x) > 0; \tag{5}$

thus when $x > 0$,

$\alpha(x) - 1 = \alpha(x) - \alpha(0)$
$= \int_0^x \alpha'(s) ds < 0, \tag{6}$

so

$\alpha(x) < 1, \tag{7}$

whence

$1 + x < e^x; \tag{7}$

also, for $x < 0$,

$1 - \alpha(x) = \alpha(0) - \alpha(x)$
$= \int_x^0 \alpha'(s) ds > 0, \tag{8}$

thus again

$\alpha(x) < 1, \tag{9}$

showing that

$1 + x < e^x \tag{10}$

in this case as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's a *local* minimum. In order to establish that it's a global minimum, you'll need to do more than take the derivative and apply the first or second derivative test.

One theorem you can use is Rolle's theorem (or the more general version, the mean value theorem). It states that if you have a function $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous, as well as differentiable on $(a, b)$, with $f(a) = f(b)$, then $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a, b)$.

In particular, you've established that $h(0) = 0$, and presumably that $h'(x)$ exists everywhere and is equal to $0$ exactly when $x = 0$. Then, if there's any other point $x$ where $h(x) = 0$, by Rolle's theorem, there must exist some point $c$ strictly between $0$ and $x$ with $h'(c) = 0$. But, $h'(c)$ cannot be $0$, since $c \neq 0$. This is a contradiction, so the minimum is *global*.

Comment: I think it is enough in this case just to mention that it is elementary function, there fore continous, therefor its _global_ minimum or one of the local minimums (in this case we have only one) or at any other trouble point, but here it is continious and we dont have any trouble points. I mean, we cant get any other point as global minimum beside the local one, arent we? 
Because of it's continuity.

Comment: Any case, thats how we search for global maximum or minimum, arent we? 
We find the local, then we take also the problematic points (where the functions has points in which the functions isnt continius and in the edges- if we investigate the functions in some interval) and then we just take the point between those, who has the biggest image value.

Comment: and here we also see the in infinity and minus infinity it is a positive infinity in both cases, but that is something worth to remind, that's you are right about it any way.

Comment: If we have a continuous function on a *compact* interval, then the maximum (and minimum) must occur where the derivative is $0$, the derivative doesn't exist, or at an endpoint of the interval. On an unbounded interval, things are a little more complicated. There are no edges. Rolle's theorem is one way to deal with this formally. It's not that what you're saying is really wrong, and it's not that far removed from what I'm saying, but citing a theorem, rather than intuition, is generally preferable in a proof.

Comment: All right, so maybe I do get some minus because of that, because we should write thing correctly and fromally. Thank you very much for your detailed and professional explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. When you get the hang of it, pay it forward. :-)

Comment: It's sufficient to look at the limits at $-\infty$ and $\infty$; both are $\infty$, meaning that the unique critical point has to be a global minimum point (as the function is everywhere differentiable).

Answer (score 2):

.....Your proof is correct.....

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me. It is worth noting that one definition of $e^x$ is $e^x = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. When looking at this definition, is is clear that the proposition is true. Since this is an infinite sum of polynomial terms, the exponential function would dominate *every* polynomial for large enough $x$.

Comment: It is not a completely trivial matter for $x<0$, since then the odd terms are negative.

Answer (score 2):

Since $h(0)=0$, we have $h(x)=\int_0^x h'(t)\,dt=\int_0^x e^t-1\,dt$.

Now, $t \mapsto e^t$ is increasing and so $e^t>e^0=1$ for $t>0$ and  $e^t<e^0=1$ for $t<0$.

This implies that $h(x)=\int_0^x e^t-1\,dt >0$ because the integrand is positive when $x>0$ and negative when $x<0$. In the latter case, $\int_0^x e^t-1\,dt = \int_x^0 -(e^t-1)\,dt >0$.

Comment: I like your technique (see my answer).  ***Endorsed!***

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x,$ which is everywhere positive. Any function with strictly positive second derivative lies above any of its tangent lines except at the points of tangency. The line tangent to $y=e^x$ at $(0,1)$ is $y=x+1.$ Therefore $e^x>1+x, x\ne 0.$