# Short proof for $1-x\leq \exp(-x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I'm trying to find a short way to show that:
$$
1-x\leq \exp(-x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}
$$

Does anyone know a really short solution for this problem?

Comment: Set $y=-x$ and apply your favourite proof from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex/504837

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** try to minimize the function
$$
f(x) = \exp(-x) - 1 + x
$$
using calculus. You will find that its unique minimum occurs at $x = 0$.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

$\exp(-x)$ is convex, so it's above its tangents, especially its tangent at 0.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to recall that

$$\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n$$

is a inceasing function of $n$ and is bounded above by its limit, $e^{-x}$.  Therefore

$$e^{-x}\ge \left(1-\frac xn\right)^n\ge 1-x$$

and we're done.

Comment: A nice alternative

Comment: @travis Just curious... am at the gym and working from a "not so smart" phone.  What was the edit?

Comment: @simons Thank you!  Much appreciative.

Comment: @Dr.MV There was a caret missing from one of the equations, so that $e^{-x}$ rendered as $e - x$. (+1 for the nice answer, btw.)

Comment: @Travis Thanks for the edit and the +1!!

Answer (score 1):

In my answer to this question,
[Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex), as well as in my answer to this one: [To show that $e^x > 1+x$ for any $x\ne 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362221/to-show-that-ex-1x-for-any-x-ne-0), I proved that

$1 + x \le e^x \tag{1}$

for all real $x$.  Many others also contributed concise and valid proofs of this fact as well; they deserve credit a much as anyone.

Given that (1) is the case, it follows that

$1 - x \le e^{-x} \tag{2}$

for all $x \in \Bbb R$ by simply replacing $x$ by $-x$ throughout.  ***QED.***